# Asp.net Web Application to Automatically add data to SQL Server Database after certain date

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am kind of new to Asp.Net but I have worked previously on HTML and PHP.

I am building an online Library Management System in Asp.Net using C# and a SQL Server 2008 R2 back end. I want to have such capability in my application that when a member delays a book return after the return date then the application must add AUTOMATICALLY an number of days that I will specify to the `Users` table in the SQL database.

I would not hope for a solution that will make the whole process clear but however any kind Help would be much appreciated in the sense the way I will have to implement this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I would simply implement a SQL JOB and schedule it to run at certain interval (say every hour or whatever is convenient). Such job will check all the users that have not returned the books on time and add the specified surcharge amount. The logic itself can be implemented in a stored procedure.

You can use SSMS to create the job and schedule it.